# What does "sehr hoch verlieren" mean?

Tags: word-usage

Among the definitions for eingehen, Duden lists

> sehr hoch verlieren.

Does this mean to lose by a lot? Why is this not

> sehr viel verlieren?

Is that incorrect? For what reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're different things. "Viel verlieren" is "to lose a lot", "hoch verlieren" is "to lose by a big margin", mainly used in sports. For example, you could say "Iran hat hoch gegen England verloren" about their 2:6 in the World Cup match earlier today.